# Formula Design System Advanced Table

Tags: azure-devops-extensions

I am attempting to use the example from the Formula Design System Advanced Table:

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/admiring-hamilton-7sf6jx?file=%2Fexample.tsx&module=example.tsx

Which is from the Microsoft documentation:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-devops/components/table#advanced-table

However when i do I get an error on the columns:

`TS2322: Type 'ITableColumn<IPipelineItem>[]' is not assignable to type 'ITableColumn<Partial<IPipelineItem>>[]'. Type 'ITableColumn<IPipelineItem>' is not assignable to type 'ITableColumn<Partial<IPipelineItem>>'. Types of property 'behaviors' are incompatible. Type 'IBehavior<ITableColumnBehaviorProps<IPipelineItem>, {}>[] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'IBehavior<ITableColumnBehaviorProps<Partial<IPipelineItem>>, {}>[] | undefined'. Type 'IBehavior<ITableColumnBehaviorProps<IPipelineItem>, {}>[]' is not assignable to type 'IBehavior<ITableColumnBehaviorProps<Partial<IPipelineItem>>, {}>[]'. Type 'IBehavior<ITableColumnBehaviorProps<IPipelineItem>, {}>' is not assignable to type 'IBehavior<ITableColumnBehaviorProps<Partial<IPipelineItem>>, {}>'.`

I see the error on the Microsoft documentation as well so I assume it's not just me. Anyone else solved this?

Comment: Did you directly use the sample in the document without any modifications, and then this error occurred? By the way, maybe you can ask your question [here](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-extension-sample/issues).